# How to remove the Certificate Enrollment Web Service role?

Tags: windows-server-2016, ad-certificate-services

I misunderstood the purpose of the Certificate Enrollment Web Service role, and I installed it by mistake during my first configuration of my new Server Essentials 2016 instance.

Now that I've discovered that I don't need it and would rather not have it, I don't seem to be able to remove it.

Note the disabled checkbox:

[image]

I tried running the `Uninstall-AdcsEnrollmentWebService` command, but I received no feedback indicating success or failure; I simply found myself back at the PowerShell command prompt. The checkbox remains disabled.

I've also tried restarting the server, all to no avail.

How can I remove this role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In server manager  click on the 'Manage' menu and select the '**Remove Roles and Features**', not add roles, the 'add roles' option doesn't let you de-select roles.
[image: remove role]

Comment: Ouch. Wish I'd seen that before I started over from scratch just now. But it may be for the best—that PowerShell command did something that was crashing Server Manager whenever I tried to go back in and reconfigure the role. Anyway, thanks for the answer. I'll definitely keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with PowerShell, you just used the wrong command to remove feature. Mentioned command did exactly what it is intended for, removed the service, however you are trying to remove the feature and its binaries. You had to use Remove-WindowsFeature command to remove the feature,

Comment: @Crypt32 — Ah, OK. Thanks for the heads-up on that. Two useful tips in a row... this is a good day :-)